# How to show path wise connectedness?

Tags: calculus

How do I show that the set $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x≥0,y≥0\}\cup\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x≤0,y≤0\}$ is path connected. I know that I need to construct a continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow A$ such that $f(0)=x,f(1)=y$ for any pair of points $x,y\in A$ but how would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $x,y\in A$. Then define the function
$$
f(t) = 
\begin{cases}
   (1 - 2t) x & \text{if } t\le\frac{1}{2} \\
   (2t -1) y       & \text{if } t \ge \frac{1}{2}
  \end{cases}.
$$
Geometrically we move from $x$ in a straight line to zero after which we move in a straight line to $y$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am a bit new to this, a hint that I was given was taking to using a pasting lemma to add the two quadrants together. But I don't quite understand. Also, who did you get (1-2t)x, and (2t-1(y)? Thanks !

Comment: We need to split the interval in two parts, one to move from the starting point to the origin and the other part to move from the origin to the second point. I split the interval into $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $[\frac{1}{2},1]$. After that you have to do a little of trial and error to find the right parametrization.

Comment: Use that when $t = 0$ you need to be in $x$. Then if $t=\frac{1}{2}$, you need to be in the origin. Same for the second part, although now you need to be in the origin for $t=\frac{1}{2}$ and in $y$ for $t=1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! That really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: separate into cases of $x,y$ both in the first quadrant, $x,y$ both in the third quadrant, and one of $x$, $y$ in the first and third quadrants. The first two cases are easy, and the third case is still quite easy, but takes a little bit more work - you just might want to visualize it (to get from the first to third quadrant, you have to go through the origin!)